# Extension method not found when publishing ASP.NET MVC app

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc, extension-methods, .net-standard-2.0, httpresponsemessage

In an ASP.NET MVC application (.NET 4.7) I am using an extension method on `HttpResponseMessage`. This method is created in a .NET Standard 2.0 project. When debugging and using IIS Express, it is working just fine.

But when publishing to a server, it returns "method not found" error. On the server (Windows Server 2008) all needed frameworks are installed.

To error got clear when I used a try/catch in the method where I called the extension method.

As in development I'm expecting that it works on the server. Am I missing any other .NET frameworks? Or does anyone else as a possible solution?

```
HttpResponseMessage response = client.GetAsync(UserManAPI).Result;
if (response.IsSuccessStatusCode)
{
    apiResponse = response.Content.ReadAsStringAsync().Result;
}
else
    response.ThrowReynaersException();


public static void ThrowReynaersException(this HttpResponseMessage response)
{
        if (response.StatusCode == HttpStatusCode.OK)
        {
            using (var dataStream = 
                    response.Content.ReadAsStreamAsync().Result)
            {
                 if (dataStream != null)
                 {
                      var jsonResponse = JsonValue.Load(dataStream);
                      if (jsonResponse != null)
                      {
                           var rex = 
               JsonConvert.DeserializeObject<ReynaersException(jsonResponse,
                            new ReynaersExceptionConverter());
                           if (rex != null) throw rex;
                           var ex = JsonConvert.DeserializeObject<Exception>(jsonResponse, new ExceptionConverter());
                           if (ex != null) throw ex.ToReynaersException(); 
                           throw new 
                        ReynaersException(ErrorResourcesKeys.DefaultMessage);
                    }
                }
            }
        }
    }
```

Thanks in advance!

Comment: I would advice to add your code into your question. It will increase the chances to get an answer and reduce the changes of having your question flagged and removed.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Try this in web.config or reinstall 'System.Net.Http' using Nuget Package

```
<configuration>
    <system.web>
         <compilation>
             <assemblies>
                <add assembly="System.Net.Http, Version=4.0.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=b03f5f7f11d50a3a"/>
             </assemblies>
          </compilation>
    </system.web>
</configuration>
```

Comment: Installing System.Net.Http as a Nuget package, which adds a dependentAssembly in web.config solved the issue. Thx @Marcelo Vismari